# ~んだよなぁ What general meaning/feeling does this give?

Tags: particles, sentence-final-particles

I understand this is a combinations of a few ending particles, but I've seen it enough times that I wonder what general feeling a native gets from it.

Examples I remember:

> 終わったんだよなぁ。
>   難しいんだよなぁ。

Comment: よ and な are 終助詞, but の is a 準体助詞 and だ is a 助動詞.

Answer (score 3):

I think we use 「～～んだよなぁ」 most often when we:

1. Draw a conclusion or confirm something in a calm but somewhat exclamatory manner

or

2. Remind someone (or often oneself) of something.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the speaker is feeling reluctant to admit it. That said, it's not so much the meaning of よ or な/ね themselves as the sentence being prolonged by somewhat easily linkable particles.